# Maintain toggle state for multiple divs during postbacks

Tags: javascript, html, slidetoggle

I have jscript to toggle divs to slide up and down.  I would like to maintain the state of these divs during postbacks.  I read on other posts I can use cookies and hidden fields, but I don't know how to use it when using multiple divs with my jscript.

Jscript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".toggle").slideUp(0);
        $(".trigger").click(function () {
            $(this).next(".toggle").slideToggle("slow");
        });
    });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<h3 class = "trigger">Section 1</h3>
<div class = "toggle">
    <p> Item 1 </p>
</div>

<h3 class = "trigger">Section 2</h3>
<div class = "toggle">
    <p> Item 1 </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution thanks to user: noth1ng.
https://forum.jquery.com/topic/slidetoggle-on-multiple-divs-to-maintain-state-during-postbacks